# SQL Server stored procedure , loop through table and get values?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

In the code shown below, I loop through a table (in this case the disciplines table) and want to add records to another table, I'm rather new to this

How can I retrieve values from those tables for the insert command?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE cdisc 
    -- check disciplines
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE test CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
        SELECT * 
        FROM tbl_portfolio 
        WHERE show = 'Ja' ;

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        DECLARE disc CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR 
            SELECT * 
            FROM disciplines;

        WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO ProjectDisciplines (Proj_id, discipline_ID) 
            VALUES (disc!ID, test!id)
        END 

        CLOSE disc
        DEALLOCATE disc
    END

    CLOSE test
    DEALLOCATE test
END
```

Comment: Maybe there are reasons to use loops in SQL, but in 10 years of MS SQL experience I had never to use it. Is there a clause which entries you like to insert into another table? Maybe you can use a simple SELECT INTO statement.

Comment: I too see no reason to use a `CURSOR`. Why not just use an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT... FROM`?

Comment: i want to add all record found in the disciplines table into the projectdisciplines table, but also with the project reference

Comment: Is there a foreign key on one of the tables?

Comment: Not really, on the front end this is the way to do it but runs rather slow.Just want to add the records for each project in the first select

Comment: You cannot match the table entries if there is no foreign key, thus I do not understand the query.

Comment: A loop inside a loop with an insert? That's terrible. Instead: `INSERT INTO ProjectDisciplines (Proj_id, discipline_ID) SELECT disc.id, test.id FROM disciplines as disc, (SELECT id from tbl_portfolio where show = 'Ja') as test;` No procedure needed and it will much much faster.  A good rule of thumb is that when working in a set based language like SQL or Pandas dataframes or Spark, do not loop. There is almost always a set based approach and it will always be faster.